# Shared library compilation gcc

Tags: c, gcc, websocket, linker-errors, undefined-reference

I am trying to compile my program that uses the libwebsockets library.

I have downloaded and compiled the libwebsockets on my linux machine and has following directory structure.

```
/libwebsockets/build/bin/  -> contains the compiled binaries (test-server,test-client etc)

/libwebsockets/build/lib/  -> contains the shared libraries. libwebsockets.so libwebsockets.a libwebsockets.so.5.0.0             

/libwebsockets/lib/ -> contains all the header files. eg: libwebsockets.h libwebsockets.c

/libwebsockets/test-server -> contains application programs..(test-server.c test-client.c etc)
```

Now I created my C program file simple-server.c in 
/libwebsockets/test-server directory.

```html
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <syslog.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <libwebsockets.h>
```

when I try to compile this program:

```
gcc -L/home/gadre/Desktop/Testing/libwebsockets/build/lib/ -lwebsockets simple-server.c -o s
```

I get linker error:

```html
simple-server.c:(.text+0x14c): undefined reference to `lwsl_emit_syslog'
simple-server.c:(.text+0x158): undefined reference to `lws_set_log_level'
simple-server.c:(.text+0x16d): undefined reference to `libwebsocket_get_internal_extensions'
simple-server.c:(.text+0x1a5): undefined reference to `libwebsocket_create_context'
simple-server.c:(.text+0x1c4): undefined reference to `_lws_log'
simple-server.c:(.text+0x1e9): undefined reference to `libwebsocket_service'
simple-server.c:(.text+0x209): undefined reference to `libwebsocket_context_destroy'
simple-server.c:(.text+0x21d): undefined reference to `_lws_log'
```

How to solve this..I tried putting the path in the LD_LIBRARY_PATH as well. but still linker cannot find the shared libraries.

Comment: Try changing the order of the source file vs. the library, ie `gcc -L/home/gadre/Desktop/Testing/libwebsockets/build/lib/ simple-server.c -lwebsockets -o s`.

Comment: Try putting #include "<path_to_libwebsockets.h_file>"because this is not in the PATH variable so can't be found.

Comment: Ok I am able to compile for now...
I used following command. with run time link option.

gcc -L/home/gadre/Desktop/Testing/libwebsockets/build/lib -Wl,-rpath=/home/gadre/Desktop/Testing/libwebsockets/build/lib -Wall -o server incr_server.c -lwebsockets.

I don't know specifics but it works for now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am able to compile for now... I used following command. with run time link option.

`gcc -L/home/gadre/Desktop/Testing/libwebsockets/build/lib -Wl,-rpath=/home/gadre/Desktop/Testing/libwebsockets/build/lib -Wall -o server incr_server.c -lwebsockets`

I don't know specifics but it works for now